# C++ 11.0 Compiler for QT 5.0? Errors

Tags: c++, qt

i have little problem with QT creator.

When i try to build or debug project i have following error with message:

**:-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.**

Then i go to

**Tools->Options->Debug** in Kits tab set new compiler and again error with message that i need old compiler, and warning with message that mine debugger is not setted up?

I googled this error, and find solution that i need to install old C++ 10 or older compiler.
Is there any other way to solve this problem, or i need to uninstall 11.0 and install 10.0?
I have installed Visual Studio 2012 full, payed edition.

Thank you.

Comment: What compiler are trying to use MinGW or MSVC?

Comment: @cmannett85 I use MSVC compiler.